# How to sort by name an Enum in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to sort an Enum by the names, I have the following code:

```
Enum.GetNames(x.options).Where(.....).Select(.....)
```

notice that `x.options` is an enum

and I would like to sort de results of the linq by the name of the Enum, how could I do it?

Comment: `var sortedNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(x.options)).OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();`. This will give you the _names_ in ascending order as a string array. Is that what you want?

Comment: Do you mean `query.OrderBy(x => x.options.ToString("G"))`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the following `enum`:

```
public enum Number
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
}
```

You need to pass the enum's type in [`Enum.GetNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Enum_GetNames_System_Type_) and then call `OrderBy` (to sort in ascending order):

```
var sortedEnum = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Number)).OrderBy(x => x);

// or, from .NET 5 onwards:
var sortedEnum = Enum.GetNames<Number>().OrderBy(x => x);
```

This will return an `IOrderedEnumerable<string>` having the following (sorted) values:

```
Four
One
Three
Two
```

Of course you could `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` the results, to return them in a list or an array, respectively.

Comment: Alternative: `Enum.GetNames<Number>()`.

Comment: @PoulBak Assuming it is .NET 5 or newer of course.

Comment: Added .NET 5+ alternative to the answer, thanks.